# Incorrect css/scss sourcemap line numbers

Tags: css, sass, gulp, source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps

Soucemaps line numbers are incorrect for multiple selectors that are on the same line. When selectors have been split into separate lines, the sourcemap line numbers are correct, otherwise they are off by one. Any idea why it behaves like this?

Am using a gulpfile and dependancies include: gulp-sass and gulp-sourcemaps

See attached [image: screenshots]